# /me in minecraft isnt disabled by the plugin I wrote

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So in my server `/me` is an enabled command. I wanted to disable this because I don't want people to be able to do this.

I'm learning java, so I decided to code something that disabled `/me` myself.

So I wrote the following code:

```
package com.ste999.disableme;

import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener 
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("disable me enabled");
        PluginManager pm = this.getServer().getPluginManager();
        pm.registerEvents(this, (this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("disable me disabled");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void OnMe(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event)
    {
        Player p = event.getPlayer();
        if(!p.hasPermission("ste999.me")) {
            if (event.getMessage().startsWith("/me")) {
                event.setCancelled(true);
                p.sendMessage("§4Dont me me!");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

with the following plugin.yml file:

```
name: Disable_Me
main: com.ste999.disableme.Main
version: 1.0
load: startup
description: this is should disable me
commands:
```

Now if someone without op would run `/me hello` it shouldn't output to the chat and the user should get a message like `Dont me me!`

But it doesn't. the user is still able to do `/me hello` without op and the code should prevent that

As I'm fairly new to java this error is probably easy to find, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a library specific question. I re-tagged your question for it.

Comment: if i recall corectly commands (chat messages starting with a `/`) do not trigger "`OnChat`" instead they trigger "`OnCommand`" Have a look for `AsyncPlayerCommandEvent` or somthing similar (No answer 'cause I am not sure if this is correct)

Comment: Hi @Mischa I couldn't find anything similar about `AsyncPlayerCommandEvent`.

Comment: @kaci I do not know if there is an asyn version but You are looking for `PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent`. This event is fired for EVERY command before ANY command executor.

Comment: So I looked into `PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent` and from what I read online it should be able to work if I just simply replaced `AsyncPlayerChatEvent` with `PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent` but it doesn't. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Mutliple things that came to my mind: Do you get an exception? Maybe you HAVE the permission `ste999.me`. Is the handler even called? does the message looks different than you think? do you write "/Me", as you only test the lowercase version? ... and more things... Try to debug your code and see where the code doesn't do what it should be doing. Then come back here and we can help you.

Comment: @Mischa I have no plugins on that server besides my own. And so far I know you can only get the `ste999.me` permission by having OP. And how do I debug my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189666/discussion-between-mischa-and-kaci).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `AsyncPlayerChatEvent` only gets called when actually typing chat messages (not commands). For commands you have to use `PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent` as wonderfully explained by Mischa in the comments. Changing the event will make it work:

```
@EventHandler
public void disableMeCommand(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent event) {
    Player p = event.getPlayer();
    if(!p.hasPermission("ste999.me")) {
        if(event.getMessage().startsWith("/me")) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
            p.sendMessage("§4Dont me me!");
        }
    }
}
```

However, note that [PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent.html) should be avoided. Luckily there is another way to disable a command completely in a bukkit server. You should have a `commands.yml` file located in your server folder. Simply add the "me" alias and set it to null inside the file:

```
aliases:
  me:
  - null
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why this event should be avoided? In fact. If OP wants to be able to control the use of `/me` with a condition the use of this event is encouraged by the linked docs: "Some examples of valid uses for this event are: [...] Conditionally blocking commands belonging to other plugins. [...]"